# SEO for multi language search with only one language (English) site

Tags: seo

I have an English site and I want to enable search my website with keywords of other languages. For example, stackoverflow.com provides only an English site, however, I can find the top search result from the google with search keyword '스택오버플로우' (I use Korean and '스택오버플로우' means 'stackoverflow' in Korean).

How can I achieve this SEO for my website?

Comment: Read more of Google https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/managing-multi-regional-sites

Comment: Hi, I've already read the document, but I think it doesn't provide the thing I want. I want to provide non-translated site with only one domain